# Mysql Unique / distinct rows based on two or more columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I have the following columns - lets call location table
city, state, zipcode, lat, lng

The problem is that every city and state can multiple zip codes e.g.

belleuve, wa, 98004
bellevue, wa, 98006

Similarly a city name can be also present in some other state e.g.

bellevue, TN, 05156

How do I select a distinct city e.g. Bellevue for each state.  Basically the result should show both Bellevue, WA and Bellevue, TN but for WA only one occurance of Bellevue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by the city and state should work here:

```
SELECT City, State
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY City, State;
```

We also could use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City, State
FROM yourTable;
```